# wrap_content breaks performance of my constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a single `TextView` which I am updating as a counter every second. If I use `wrap_content` for its width, I get performance warnings that it takes 50ms to draw the view update in the layout/measure phase. When I programmatically set its width and height, it addresses the alerts, but my views no longer resize (obviously :). What am I missing here? Is there way to minimize view invalidations / resizing to be only when the text changes to a greater width? Do I have to do that programmatically and calculate the new size each time I update the view?

Comment: i am no sure but setting min_height = "spesific dp" and height = "wrap_content" may fix your issue.

Comment: i think you must set TextView dimension to static values to prevent resize fired in change event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a solution to why it was happening in the first place, but a workout around (Which feels very anti-android since it doesn't rely on ConstraintLayout to solve what hopefully is a simple system of equations to determine the proper intrinsic TextView width without breaking the whole UI thread):

```
fun TextView.conditionallyChangeWidthWithNewString(newString: CharSequence) {
   val calculatedWidth = getWidthOfNewText(newString.toString())
   if (calculatedWidth > layoutParams.width) {
       val params = getLayoutParams()
       params.width = calculatedWidth
       setLayoutParams(params)
   }
   setTextIfChanged(newString)
}

fun TextView.getWidthOfNewText(s: String): Int {
   val p = Paint()
   val bounds = Rect()
   val plain = typeface
   p.setTypeface(plain)
   p.textSize = textSize
   p.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length, bounds)
   val mt = p.measureText(s)
   return mt.toInt()
}
```